# What can I do to synchronize the desktop and documents of two computers on a local network?

Tags: macos, backup, rsync, local-network

My parents got two shiny new iMac's (2015, 27") for Christmas, and for the first time ever they have separate computers. The problem is, they want everything between them to be the same. For now, I've copied both Desktop and Documents folders from the old computer (the only folders they really used), amounting to about 70GB of stuff. The problem is keeping things synced after I leave to head back to school.

Dropbox, SugarSync, SkyDrive, etc are out, as the amount of data is way past their limits, and privacy issues are there.

I was thinking of doing rsync in a cron job, to mimic how something like SyncBack Free may do this, but am very open to suggestions. Ideally, there would be two way synchronization, with most recent edits being written to the computer with the older version.

What would such a script look like? Can it be done for free?

Comment: Your first mistake was agreeing to help your parents with their computers. Good luck! I know you don't want to use dropbox, but it is secure, and the probably the easiest option.

Comment: For 70GB though? It's also only over the local network, so there's gotta be something I can do, right?

Comment: Maybe something here will work for you? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103640/automaticallly-sync-select-folders-between-two-macs-over-lan